# gateway lost after upgrade to wheezy

Tags: debian, gateway, debian-wheezy

After upgrade from squeezy to wheezy my network configuration lost gateway.

(i have lxc containers, and all of wheezy losts, one, which i want to stay squeezy - still have, so i'm sure, that the problem is of wheezy upgrade)

I have to add manually route add default gw x.x.x.x eth0 to bring back - but reboot remove it of course.

What is the correct way to set gateway on wheezy?

my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 172.16.0.5
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 172.16.0.1
  broadcast 172.16.0.255
```

====================================== added ========================

```
#netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

I'm definetely sure that wheezy breaks sth.
I found, that i have one more squeeze container (not important) which has gateway working - i upgraded it and gateway is lost..

I don't use any NetworkManager (intentionaly) - no gui at all

Comment: Could you add the result of "netstat -rn" run in a faulty container ?

Comment: I wonder if lxc config isn't changed in wheezy

Answer (score 1):

I found it!

The problem is in lxc conf file.

In squeezy the network section looks:

```
lxc.utsname = container1
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = br0
lxc.network.name = eth0
lxc.network.ipv4 = 172.16.0.5/24
```

in wheezy - you have to add this line:

```
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = auto
```

Comment: not really - if you set .gateway to auto, it's set to your ip of your main host running containers. You may possibly have to turn on forwarding to make it work, but I didn't check this. If you have br0 interface, I'd rather say you need to set up your actual gateway ip, like lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 1.2.3.4. But thanks to your post I found what was wrong with my config.

Answer (score 0):

The `gateway` directive in your [interfaces](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%20testing%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en) file is still the preferred way to configure these settings. You should make sure that an autoconfiguration tool such NetworkManager did not accidentally get installed during your upgrade process or that you are not using init scripts to add or remove extra static routes.

Comment: as i wrote up: no intentionaly autoconfiguration tools and manual scripts - lxc containers are as simple as it is possible...